# Delete parent record if child record does not exist CONSTRAINT PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, delete-row

I am creating a small database to store information about hotel bookings and customers.

I want to make it so that a room record in the room table can be deleted only if there are no bookings for a hotel room.

The way I'm trying to solve the problem is by doing:

```
FOREIGN KEY (hid, room) REFERENCES room (hid, num) 
ON DELETE CASCADE WHEN NOT EXISTS(hid AND room)
```

but it isn't working.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it?

```
CREATE TABLE booking( hid CHAR(4) NOT NULL, 
cid CHAR(4) NOT NULL,    
dstart DATE NOT NULL,    
ndays DATE,    
room INTEGER,     
PRIMARY KEY(hid, cid, dstart), 
FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES customer (cid)    
ON UPDATE CASCADE    
ON DELETE CASCADE,    
FOREIGN KEY (hid, room) REFERENCES room (hid, num)    
ON DELETE CASCADE WHEN NOT EXISTS(hid AND room)    
);
```

Comment: That is not how relationships work. You'll have to do that manually. `on delete cascade` works for e.g. when you remove a room, remove all corresponding bookings.

Comment: Can I make so that when I remove a room, it will remove all corresponding bookings ONLY IF there are no bookings for a hotel room? Thank you for your response. @GurV

Comment: Try reading your comment. You are saying when removing a room, remove all bookings for that room when there is no booking for that. Doesn't make sense. Also, the default behavior `NO ACTION` doesn't let the parent row get deleted when child are present, which I think is what you want.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. I was supposed to say:
 
Can I make it so that a room record in the room table can be deleted only if there are no bookings for a hotel room? 

So I tried the ON DELETE NO ACTION, and it works. Thank you! @GurV

Answer (score 0):

You need to define one delete rule per foreign key relationship.

Example, if the existence of a booking as a child record should prevent deletes, then use ON DELETE RESTRICT, which is also the default rule if you don't explicitly state one. There are no additional parameters to an ON DELETE rule: the EXISTS clause you're trying is not possible.